# How do I append a text after an element has faded out completely?

Tags: jquery

I want to append a class .Appear only after ensuring the element has been removed completely..How can I achieve this?

```
<html>
 <body>
     <div id="Append"></div>
 </body>
</html>

$(function(){
$(".Appear").stop().fadeOut("fast",function(){
    $(this).remove();
    alert(123);
    })

   $("#Append").append("<span class='Appear'>Appear</span>"); alert(8);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uyPJB/

Comment: not very clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to keep fading out the element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
    var $appear = $("<span class='Appear'>Appear</span>")
    $("#Append").append($appear)
    $appear.fadeOut("fast",function(){$(this).remove();});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VGp2U/

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(".Appear").stop(true,true).fadeOut("slow",function(){
        $(this).remove();
        alert(123);
         $("#Append").append("<span class='Appear'>Appear</span>");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uyPJB/4/